# Host a mvc web api application in the sub-folder of a website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I already have a web application in the root folder of my website. (e.g. http://cassapi.gear.host). Now I want to add one MVC web API application in a subfolder inside the '`wwwroot`' folder, so that I can access my home controller something like "http://cassapi.gear.host/DOTAPI/api/values" without troubling the website in the '`wwwroot`' folder.

**Note:** It's working fine when I publish this MVC application in the root folder.

My web.config is like this :-

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

My root config:-

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "DOTAPI/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

i am a windows application developer and new in MVC. so, please look into this and help me.

Currently , when i am calling the url "http://cassapi.gear.host/DOTAPI/" it shows "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting a access denied error, then you must give permissions to `iis_users` group for your directory. And there is another way for achieving what you need. You can add your `api` as an application to your main website. Below are the steps.

1. Go to IIS.
2. Right click your main website and choose `Add Application`.
3. Give an alias for your api.
4. Set the path to your API folder.

Then you can just browse your API with the alias you provided.

Comment: Also try various URL combinations when testing, with and without `api`

Comment: @sunny verma . It's working fine on IIS if I add it as an application ,providing an alias name. My problem is that I am not been able to do it in case of web hosting. there is no option there for adding the application. we can add a subfolder. but it's not working after doing that